# Why my Vim slowing down in rails dir?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, rails.vim

I notice that in my rails projects vim starting about 2 sec.

I investigating that issue and I know that this happen because of rails.vim plugin.

Here are my logs from vim: https://gist.github.com/807735fb2dd4bd82656b#file-vim-in-rails-dir-log-L97

Is there any chance to improve that startup time?

Comment: That's probably due to rails.vim calling Ruby to e.g. determine the include path.

Comment: I set up ``let g:ruby_path = system('echo $HOME/.rbenv/shims')`` but whichout success and also updated Gist with my vimrc and PATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with bundler.vim plugin to Vim. I opened issue on Github:
https://github.com/tpope/vim-bundler/issues/15